# Using STDIN in ruby , how to print out the multiline comments without REGEX

Tags: ruby, stdin

Given STDIN with the following:

`=begin This is a multiline comment and con spwan 
as many lines as you like. But =begin and =end 
should come in the first line only. 
=end`

Without using regex , how do you print the in between line as well?
(side question, is ARGF expensive since it has to wait for all the input?)

this is a start:

```
starting = "=begin"
ending = "=end"
ARGF.each do | line |
  comments = false
  if line.include?(starting) && !line.include?(ending) 
   incomments = true
  end
  if !line.include?(starting) && line.include?(ending) 
   puts line
   incomments = false
  end
  if incomments == true 
    puts line.lstrip
  end
end
```

expected output is:

`This is a multiline comment and con spwan
as many lines as you like. But =begin and =end
should come in the first line only.`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @mudasobwa, I edited to show you the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The generic answer that works for any number of nested levels:

```
input = "..." # could be taken from ARGF
input.
  split($/).
  each_with_object(result: Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}, level: 0) do |line, acc|
    acc[:level] += 1 if line.include?('=begin')
    (1..acc[:level]).each do |level|
      acc[:result]["Level: #{level}"] << line
    end
    acc[:level] -= 1 if line.include?('=end');
  end[:result]

#⇒ {
#    "Level: 1" => [
#      "=begin This is a multiline comment and con spwan as many lines as you like.",
#      "But =begin and =end should come in the first line only.",
#      "=end"
#    ],
#    "Level: 2" => [
#      "But =begin and =end should come in the first line only."
#    ]
# }
```

If you need the comments on top level, just get the value for `"Level: 1"` key and join it with `$/` delimiter.

Comment: taking all of the input at once is expensive. it should be written for each line as it comes in.

Comment: I doubt you understand what “expensive” means and how it applies here. Unless you expect to work with GB inputs _only_, any check for “expensive” is a premature optimization, which _must be avoided_. Despite all that, the solution above works pretty well with `ARGF` and might be turned to `Enumerator::Lazy` by just embedding `lazy` in the chain of method calls.